# iOS Firebase crash reporting warning

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm starting to use Firebase crash reporting for my iOS project (I have enabled Firebase and everything working fine, get sample crash appear on dashboard).

But the only strange thing is that I get bunch of warning in my Xcode console (Xcode 8.1). How do we to get rid of the warning?

Here is my screenshot of the warning:

[image]

Some warning console messages:

```
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: in compilation unit '/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/App/Version8c/SingPost/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/collection_change_builder.cpp' (offset 0x100318):
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x142603 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x14259e, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x149667 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x12fb7b, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x149e2d has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x12fbc8, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x14b958 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x1322de, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x14c766 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x1323cd, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x14cbdf has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x14b982, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: warning: function at offset 0x14cbdf has no name
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x14cda5 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x132409, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x1522ed has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x1398bd, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x152bf8 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x152329, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x152c7c has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x139908, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x154dca has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x13b14a, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x155718 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x13b726, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x159fb5 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x143410, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x15a038 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x14345d, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x15a0bb has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x1453c6, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: the DIE at offset 0x15a397 has a DW_AT_specification attribute referring to the die at offset 0x1434aa, which either was not marked as a declaration, or comes later in the file
warning: dump_syms: /Users/victory1908/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SingPost-bsyrfyuoahxzibgwthrzgvnckyff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SingPost.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SingPost: in compilation unit '/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/App/Version8c/SingPost/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp' (offset 0x15a565):
```

Comment: Who use firebase crash report for IOS? can have your advice?

Comment: I have the same issue, 565 warnings, I've emailed Firebase support and waiting for a reply.

Comment: I have the same problem , after I add firebase crash report , you resolved this ?

Comment: I used to be fine without warnings. But suddenly I encounter the same issue and I have hundreds of warning in my Xcode when I build/archive my app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/46

TL;DR - Seems to be a Firebase issue but doesn't have any impact to project. Warnings only show up when Archiving. They have no ETA to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Try : Build Phases --> Run Script

Click " Run script only when installing ''

it should be solving your issue.